# submit a form on onchange event of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form on on-change event of any check-box. here, I have many check-boxes surrounded with label tags but whenever a change event occurs the serialize() method returns a null value for form parameters instead of value entered. Does the label tag affects the working of Ajax?I am new to Ajax, so may be there is only a minor mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

JavaScript

```
<script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = $('#ajaxform');

    $("#ajaxform input:checkbox").on('change',function () {
        //alert(this.name+' '+this.value+' '+this.checked);
        $.ajax({
             type: form.attr('method'),
             url: form.attr('action'),
             data: $(this).parent("form").serialize(),
             success: function (data) {
                 var result=data;
                 $('#content').html(result);
             }
         });

         return false;
     }); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Ajax form Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='content'>
    </div>
    <form id='ajaxform' name='ajaxform' action='./ajaxformexample' method='post'>

      First Name:
      <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' size='30' required/>
      <br/>Last Name:
      <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' size='30' required/>
      <br/>Email:
      <input type='email' id='emailid' name='emailid' size='30' required/>
      <br/>Password:
      <input type='password' id='pwd' name='pwd' size='30' required/>
      <br/>checkbox:
      <input type='checkbox' id='cb' name='cb' value='1' />
      <br/>checkbox2:
      <input type='checkbox' id='cb1' name='cb1' />
      <br/>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="50-200" name="price">50-200</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="200-500" name="price">200-500</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="500-1000" name="price">500-1000</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1000-1500" name="price">1000-1500</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1500-3000" name="price">1500-3000</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3000-5000" name="price">3000-5000</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="5000-10000" name="price">5000-10000</label>
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="10000-50000" name="price">10000-50000</label>

    </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

In the above code, when i remove the label element, it works fine and i get all the expected parameter values, but when i use label it returns null instead of parameter values.

Comment: try after changing the class name of label, `class="checkbox_abc"` or anything else...

Comment: still not working @ManjeetBarnala

Comment: i tries to remove class attribute, but it is not working properly. so i guess it has to do something with label.

Comment: Try `$("#ajaxform").on('change','input[type="checkbox"]', function () {`

Comment: this is working correctly! I am getting the entered value for all parameters but this redirects me on servlet and i am getting output on servlet, and i want my output on index.jsp.

Comment: `$("#ajaxform").serialize()` would be better than what you have with `$(this).parent("form").serialize()` since that IS the form.  I noted issues with the latter in some testing where it would with your form not produce any values (empty) at times but not with the suggested.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, This is showing output on my ajaxformexample.java servlet page. Is there something so that I can show the same result on my index.jsp.

Comment: There is one more thing I noticed. Whenever I try to add css, or surround form element or other input field by <div>, the parameter values becomes null.

Comment: I put your html and Javascript in a fiddle here and that part seems to work.  I also added CSS and a DIV https://jsfiddle.net/a28raLk1/1/

Answer (score 1):

`onchnge` should be `onchange`  (not needed at all BTW)

`$("#ajaxform input: checkbox ")` should be `$("#ajaxform input:checkbox")`

```
< script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" > < /script>
```

is shitty markup:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

is much better.

Also you should better use only your event listeners instead of those inline JS
so remove every `onchnge="document.ajaxform.submit();"`

Also `name="price">>50-200</label>` should be `name="price">50-200</label>`

Additionally, since you're using AJAX to send data to PHP? you could use an extension like

```
./ajaxformexample.php
```

or whatever the file is, but most importantly you need to **prevent the default FORM submission**!

**Here's an example:**

```js
$("#ajaxform").on("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var serializedData = $(this).serialize();

  alert( serializedData );

  $.ajax({
    type: this.method,
    url:  this.action,
    data: serializedData,
    success: function (data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    }
  });

}).on("change", ":checkbox", function(){
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='ajaxform' action='./ajaxformexample.php' method='post'>

  First Name:
  <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' size='30' required/>
  <br/>Last Name:
  <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' size='30' required/>
  <br/>Email:
  <input type='email' id='emailid' name='emailid' size='30' required/>
  <br/>Password:
  <input type='password' id='pwd' name='pwd' size='30' required/>
  <br/>checkbox:
  <input type='checkbox' id='cb' name='cb' value='1' />
  <br/>checkbox2:
  <input type='checkbox' id='cb1' name='cb1' />
  <br/>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="50-200" name="price">50-200</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="200-500" name="price">200-500</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="500-1000" name="price">500-1000</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1000-1500" name="price">1000-1500</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1500-3000" name="price">1500-3000</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="3000-5000" name="price">3000-5000</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="5000-10000" name="price">5000-10000</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="10000-50000" name="price">10000-50000</label>

</form>
```

Comment: before this, i tried onchange event, but the function did not work. after that i googled and found this code. this is working fine when i remove the label element.

Comment: @baby_401 there's nothign wrong in using label the way you use it, you have just an issue with `name="price">>50-200</label>` should be `name="price">50-200</label>`

Comment: @baby_401 stop using Word or notepad for code editing. Find a better text editor with code highlighting that will alert on such formatting issues.

Comment: i made all the changes u suggested, but whenever i check the check-boxes surrounded with label element, it is still sending null value for the parameters. Works fine for the first two check-boxes without label attribute

Comment: @baby_401 added an example. Everything will work fine if you follow every suggestion.

Comment: ..i edited the code. here i have used java servlet, not php. so ajaxformexample is a servlet name. now all the check-boxes are working correctly i guess, as i get the correct serialized string in alert dialog. but when it is submitted to servlet, all parameter values become null. basically, i want all the selected parameter values to be displayed on the same page where i have created my form.

Comment: `.find(":checkbox").on("change", function(){` might also be written as `.on("change","input[type=checkbox]", function(){`

Comment: Now onchange event for any check-box ,returns null value for all parameters. can it be a servlet error? @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss or even like `.on("change",":checkbox", function(){` ;)

Comment: The input is preferred as it allows some modern browser optimization that `:checkbox` does not.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ? huh? What browser optimization are you talking about? Both `:checkbox` and `attribute` selectors (Selectors Level 3) trigger the Sizzle selector engine.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ and https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki

Comment: Just a reference to " For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead." on https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/  They both DO work, not debating that fact.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add: `dataType: "json",` to your ajax as here in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/a28raLk1/5/

Note I also put the `var form = $('#ajaxform');` inside the function to avoid the global.  I don't have a lot of insight into the java side me being primarily a .Net developer.

Here is the code from that:

```
$("#ajaxform").on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var form = $('#ajaxform');
  var mydata = $("#ajaxform").serialize();
  $('#serialcontent').html($("#ajaxform").serialize());
  console.dir($("#ajaxform").serialize());
  $.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    dataType: "json",
    data: mydata,
    success: function(data) {
      var result = data;
      $('#content').html(result);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```